# div innerhtml object access parent html div

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

I have a **main.html** containing the following div:

```
<div id="main">
```

I want to dynamically load html in this div (say **page1.html** and **page2.html**). I am able to accomplish this through the following code :

```
document.getElementById("main").innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="page1.html" ></object>';
```

Now, I want to have a button id="btn1" in my **page1.html**, which should load **page2.html** into div "main" of my parent **main.html**.
However, in page1.html, I am not able to locate my container div "main"

```
document.getElementById("main") // returns null
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Dont' use an object tag, use ajax to load the content, and then insert that content into the DOM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is trying to use a single page's DOM to interact with content loaded in through an `iframe` or `object`. Using these makes life very difficult for a JavaScript developer.

If you are using only plain JavaScript, I would suggest you instead use an AJAX request to load in HTML directly through the DOM instead of transcluding this content using old methods.

Here's a beginner's guide to plain-JS AJAX. Frameworks like jQuery simplify the process immensely.
http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-make-ajax-requests-with-raw-javascript--net-4855

Otherwise, no. You cannot access that node's content because of Cross-Site Scripting security features.

Comment: Thanks, that really helped :)